# Using trim function within a countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It seems like it should be easy to do but been searching online for ages and can't make this work:

I have a column with Yes/No values only but at some point, someone entered "Yes " (i.e. with a space after).  I'm trying to use countif to count the number of "Yes"s but it's ignoring those cells with a space after the "Yes".

I tried using:

`=COUNTIF(TRIM(Sheet1!P:P),"yes")`

But I get an error.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel probably that the result is lower than it should be.

Comment: Why not trim the yes/no column? Or make it a list box with usable/selectable values yes or no.

Answer (score 2):

So, use a wildcard:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!P:P,"yes*")
```

However, I would select that particular column and do an edit:Find:replace to find "yes " and replace with "yes".